# Is it possible to use 2 server-side languages to render 2 different web pages within the same domain

Tags: python, node.js, server-side

Just as a practice I decided to embed outputs from different programming languages into my server-side language through child-processes and I was wondering can I let's say render *www.mywebsite.com/mynode* web page with **Node** as a server-side and *www.mywebsite.com/mypython* web page with **Python** as a server-side? I know it doesn't sound very practical but still..

Comment: Look into iptables, and route your node app port to port 80
You will then need to route to the correct directory within whatever you are using to render your python site. (apache, nginx, other)

Answer (score 3):

You can use reverse proxy such as [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) to archive this.

For example:

- Node is running at port 8080
- Python (Flask) is running at port 9090
- Setup Nginx to run on it's normal ports (80/443 for HTTP/S).
- Setup rules in /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/default and forward mynode path to 8080 but forward mypython to port 9090.

Please let me know if you need more clear configuration example.